Table in Dataverse will not add to Canvas app on first attempt, always requires to add a second time before it shows up in the Data Sources
My Account Types table will not add to Canvas apps on first attempt, second attempt it will add but adds '_1' to the name.  I have reached out on multiple community blogs and haven't had any luck in getting some help.  This is the only table that causes issues.  I did not create the table but I've compared it to other tables and it all seems to be good.  I'm obviously missing something.
Here is the error message: *Something went wrong while creating your app. Please try again.
StackLength: 1506
Stack: Core.ApplicationError
at n.t [as constructor] (https://authoringcdn-prodwusil108.azureedge.net/v3.24074.14.304176977/studio/js/Core.js?v=3.24074.14.304176977:2:322897)
at new t (https://authoringcdn-prodwusil108.azureedge.net/v3.24074.14.304176977/studio/js/Core.js?v=3.24074.14.304176977:2:397887)
*
I've tried adding the table different ways to canvas apps with zero luck. I have reached out on different community groups with no responses.  It is the same in both test and production environments.
Thank you for any suggestions!
Erica
